# Does Mysql Text DataType reserves any memory space

Tags: mysql, memory, text, types

I want to know if mysql `TEXT` data type reserves any space even if there is no data in that row?

I am little confuse. Can anyone provide me any input on this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Typically, no. `text` columns are actually stored away from the row, so they don't take up space on the row, per se. Instead, the row keeps a pointer to the `text` column (which *does* take up space, but only 4 bytes-ish (depends on the system) a row), but the `text` column itself will remain empty until you populate it.

Now, `varchar` columns will allocate space for their max at insertion, but only take up the space needed by its contents. `char` columns, however, will always use the space specified. So, here's what each column looks like with the phrase "waffles":

```
varchar(15): 'waffles'
char(15):    'waffles        '
text:        'waffles'
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: does this hold true for all types of Text, i.e MediumText, LongText etc? I am using inno-db engine for now. Also wanted to confirm if it does any kind of compaction, I mean if I put only 10 Bytes in Text field, will it do some compaction or acquire whole 64 KB?